# Dynamic offset for window functions alternative in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to calculate the the value of a column on the last day of the prior month, using window functions.

the following is the only way I can think of doing this, but dynamic offsets are not a thing.

```
SELECT 
        equity, 
        lagInFrame(equity) over (partition by accountId ORDER BY tradeDate ASC RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND (DATE_DIFF('day', toStartOfMonth(tradeDate), tradeDate)) preceding) as priorMonthEquity
FROM equity_table;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

CLARIFICATION:

The reason I want to use a window function and not a subquery in the select is that I want a column that I'm creating in the select.

Therefore it would be more accurate to say I want the following.

```
SELECT 
        func(equity) as newEquityStat, 
        lagInFrame(newEquityStat) over (partition by accountId ORDER BY tradeDate ASC RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND (DATE_DIFF('day', toStartOfMonth(tradeDate), tradeDate)) preceding) as priorMonthEquity
FROM equity_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to know what the last day of the previous month is? You can use `toStartOfMonth()` and subtract 1:

```
WITH 
   toDate('2023-03-30') AS this_month
SELECT 
   toStartOfMonth(this_month) - 1


┌─minus(toStartOfMonth(this_month), 1)─┐
│                           2023-02-28 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So your query would look like:

```
SELECT equity
FROM equity_table
WHERE trade_date = toStartOfMonth(now()) - 1;
```

Comment: I added a clarification to my question. Subqueries work except I need to 'window' over something I just created.